# Missing "OK" button and some on Insert Table/Form in BI Publisher

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

There is no OK button on the Table/Form. I tried restarting Microsoft Word but nothing happens.

[image: MS Word BI Publisher Insert Table/Form]

Answer (score 0):

There is no bug .This is just a previewer where you can select a group and drop nodes for preview.
To close this, you will find a separate window in window's toolbar